# Help in identifying Scandinavian dessert recipe

Tags: dessert, food-identification

Background -- I made this recipe as part of a group project (in college) that was preparing different foods from around the world. My group had Scandinavia, but as I didn't find this recipe (one of the girls in the group did), I don't know which country the recipe originates from.

I recall it being a simple recipe, but I'd like to see if I can find the full recipe. From what I remember, it required:

1. 2-3 egg whites, which were whipped into a froth
2. melting a mixture of dark and milk chocolate morsels together

Both of these were poured onto a cake/cookie layer that had been rolled out in a sheet like way, and then left to freeze overnight. This layer of the dessert was almost wafer like, but was very crumbly (but not very crunchy).

It may or may not contain nuts.

Comment: Do you have any way to contact members of that group by any chance? Somebody else might remember more details.

Comment: Ha -- I was thinking someone would ask that question. Unfortunately, after the project was done, the recipes were thrown out (much to our dismay, as this recipe had been the most popular by far), and no one could find it again. Sadly, it's another example of the one thing Google can never find: "The really awesome thing you forgot to bookmark"

Comment: So was it ever baked? How thick was the "cake/cookie" layer? Did you make that layer, too? The more you can remember, the better able we will be to help you.

Comment: Never heard of it sorry, not a well known Swedish recipe I would say, if that helps.

Comment: This might not be Scandinavian in origin, but it matches your general description : http://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-halfway-cookie-bars-117438

Comment: It's not a well known Norwegian recipe either, so that makes it Danish, I guess?

Comment: Whipped egg whites and chocolate is basically Mousse au Chocolat. So a Mousse au Chocolat cake without baking, where the cake base is made out of crumbled cookies seems to be the direction you should investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it was a variant of [chokladbiskvier](http://bit.ly/1gZBVG7), a Swedish macaroon?

Comment: Definitely in the same family of recipes. With the amount of time that's passed, I can't be 100% certain, but it's close enough that I'm going to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds most similar to a [Swiss roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_roll) (although technically not Swiss) or a variation on a [Yule log cake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yule_log_(cake)) (which may or may not have its roots in Scandinavian culture, depending on who you ask).

Comment: I believe you may have misread the question. The OP mentions a layer rolled flat into a sheet, not rolling it into a roll.

Answer (score -2):

Well, sounds more like German printen typical in Aachen area..

Comment: http://www.examiner.com/article/german-town-of-aachen-famous-for-sweet-printen-cookies

The two recipes don't look very similar?

Comment: Printen are small pieces of gingerbread. Sometimes they are coated in pure chocolate. But they aren't coated in a chocolate mousse. Also it is not a cakelike thing with a single large layer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to cooking.SE! It may be helpful to add more detail to your answer to explain why you think it might be similar to Printen, as it doesn't seem similar to others.